# React - component ref isn't created soon enough

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here goes the [codepen](http://codepen.io/FredyC/pen/gpzoXL?editors=001). It works nicely by this way. You can type text into editor and it will be updated in a display area. However I also want to have some default text in the editor, that gets displayed in a display right away after rendering.

I tried simply like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.onInput();
}
```

For some reason this is too soon or something. The `ref` for `display` component in a `application` isn't ready yet. What could be an issue please? Would you perhaps recommend some other approach?

**Clarification**: Text into Editor will be loaded from a database. Application will provide some processing on entered text and pass the results into Display component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you to move the state into the `Application` and use the `Editor` and `Display` as stateless, reusable components. With this solution you can leave out the refs altogether.

I forked and edited your [codepen](http://codepen.io/conrad/pen/pJVprL?editors=001) with the proposed solution.

I guess the problem is that the refs are resolved after the 'componentDidMount`-callbacks were called. But I'm not 100% sure about that.